# How to map a 2D numpy array onto a 1D array with another 2D array as a map?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have two 2D numpy arrays, `data` containing the actual sample data:

```
[[12 15  5  0]
 [ 3 11  3  7]
 [ 9  3  5  2]
 [ 4  7  6  8]]
```

and the other, `location`, containing a map, another 2D array of unique, non-overlapping int values corresponding to the spaces in a new 1D array of the same size as the two:

```
[[ 5  6  9 10]
 [ 4  7  8 11]
 [ 3  2 13 12]
 [ 0  1 14 15]]
```

The only way I've been able to run the transfer so far is with a simple for loop:

```
arr = np.zeros(4*4, dtype = int)

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        mapval = location[i, j]
        arr[mapval] = data[i, j]
```

Which does correctly output `[ 4  7  3  9  3 12 15 11  3  5  0  7  2  5  6  8]`

This is fine with the simple 4*4 array, but the actual dataset clocks in at 512*512, and this method takes rather very long to complete. So my question is, are there any functions, or methods exploiting ufuncs/numpy's fast processing capabilities to get this done more efficiently?

Comment: Does your map describe a *Hilbert curve* ?

Comment: Yes, it does actually!

Comment: How about simply the assignment `arr[location] = data` after the zeros initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the index that sorts the *location* array to reorder the *data* array, which can be calculated using [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
data.ravel()[location.ravel().argsort()]
# array([ 4,  7,  3,  9,  3, 12, 15, 11,  3,  5,  0,  7,  2,  5,  6,  8])
```

---

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[12, 15,  5,  0],
 [ 3, 11,  3,  7],
 [ 9,  3,  5,  2],
 [ 4,  7,  6,  8]])

location = np.array([[ 5,  6,  9, 10],
 [ 4,  7,  8, 11],
 [ 3,  2, 13, 12],
 [ 0,  1, 14, 15]])
```

Comment: Haven't encountered the ravel method before, but this works great, and only more reason now to dive into the documentation. Thanks!